# Magento admin backend not saving ANY changes - tried all common solutions NO LUCK

Tags: magento-1, backend, admin-panel

Magento admin area not updating any changes. Examples are the following;

System>Configuration>Advanced Tab>Advanced - Change any NONcore module from enable to disable>save config

= Reverts back to all enabled

Configuration Scope = Main Website>System>Configuration>Advanced Tab>Developer - Change Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints to No>Save Config

=Reverts back to Yes/Yes

-I have cleared var Cache and deleted

-I have changed configuration scope to each separate view trying to change

-I have flushed magento cache and cache storage (screenshot attached)
[image: Screenshot1]

-I have selected all cache type and refreshed

**I noticed some threads about Amasty extensions causing this issue but since this issue prevents me from disabling any extension I can not rule it out. (screenshot attached of Amasty Modules)
[image: Amasty Modules]

Comment: FYI, the "Disable Module Output" does not actually disable modules... it only hides their output on the frontend and admin.

Answer (score 2):

Modify .htaccess

RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Hope your issue will resolve..

Comment: This worked for me . I had modified my htaccess and applied a redirection. i commented that and admin saving is working again. Thanks much brother.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is an error with one of the custom/commercial extensions, and based on your screenshots... you really have a lot of them.

The one that concerns me the most is the warning from Mirasvit. It would be really mean of them to disable any post actions in the admin when the user license has expired/invalid, but almost anything is possible with a 3rd-party extension. (I've seen a LOT of 3rd-party code which really causes a lot of problems -- which is one of the major advantages of Magento 2.x).

How mission critical is this site? Are you able to bring it down for a while in order to test... such as a low traffic period?

If no, then it will be more difficult especially with extensions that are bound to host/IPs licenses trying to run on your localhost or development server.

Basically its a matter of elimination. Each step requires clearing of the cache and requires direct access to the server (SSH is preferred).

**NOTE: if you are running on the production server, you can really screw things up if you aren't careful. Make a backup of database and files before you start is HIGHLY recommended.**

Here are the steps:

- **Disable ALL local extensions**:

  - Open the `app/etc/local.xml`
  - Change `disable_local_modules` to **true**
  - Clear Cache and test... if works, then error is SOMEWHERE in `app/code/local`
- **Disable ALL commerical extensions**:

  - Rename folder `app/code/community` to `app/code/community2`
  - Clear Cache and test... if works, then error is SOMEWHERE in `app/code/local`

Chances are you break the site when you disable so many extensions... especially if the extensions add EAV models (cannot load model because extension(s) do not exist).

Once you figure out which major directory the offending code lives in, you will need to disable each one separately. **(Don't forget to reset your changes from above!!)**

- Locate the file for the extension in `app/etc/modules/*`
- Edit the file, changing `active` from true to false
- Flush Cache, and test

Once you find the extension(s) that are causing the problem, you have to decide if they are mission critical to the website. If they are, try to get the latest updates first... before you try to modify the code yourself.

Its a good idea to make sure that you are up to date with all of the latest versions of the extensions.